# Applying function to data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below. I would like to apply a function I have defined ( hurst() ) to each column (it takes a time series as an argument) and then output the results to another data frame.

```
def hurst(ts):
    #returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts

    # Create the range of lag values
    lags = range (1,5)

    # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

    # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent
    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)

    # Return the Hurst exponent from the polyfit output

    return poly[0]*2.0
```

How do I get from this

[image]

to

[image]

The full data frame has a 1y Dt history and continues E, F etc

Comment: What's wrong with `df.sum()`? it would help to accurately define your problem as this simplified example already has an answer

Comment: Yes.  Look at `apply` df.apply(yourFunction) either column-wise or row-wise (not recommended).

Comment: my function is below, but using df.apply(hurst,axis=1) I get a You cannot change part of an array error. 

def hurst(ts):
    #returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts

    # Create the range of lag values
    lags = range (2,50)

    # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

    # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent
    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)

    # Return the Hurst exponent from the polyfit output

    return poly[0]*2.0

Comment: @S.Peters please add your code to the question and make sure that you have a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).